# Modify stat_cor function to output "rho" instead of "R"

Tags: r

Is there any way to change the output expression of the function stat_cor (ggpubr package) from "R" to "rho"?  Here is a simple example to generate a plot with the "R" expression:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
p + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)+
  stat_cor(method="pearson", aes(wt, mpg), label.x = 3, 
           label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = "top")
```

I tried the `trace(stat_cor, edit=TRUE)` option and 
got the following code:

```
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, method = "pearson", label.sep = ", ", 
  label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = "top", label.x = NULL, 
  label.y = NULL, output.type = "expression", geom = "text", 
  position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
  inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) 
{
  parse <- ifelse(output.type == "expression", TRUE, FALSE)
  layer(stat = StatCor, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
    params = list(label.x.npc = label.x.npc, label.y.npc = label.y.npc, 
      label.x = label.x, label.y = label.y, label.sep = label.sep, 
      method = method, output.type = output.type, parse = parse, 
      na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

but I wasn't able to figure out which lines require modifications.
Thank you in advance for the helpful ideas.

Comment: Try `trace(ggpubr:::.cor_test, edit=TRUE)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels are defined in source file `ggpubr/R/stat_cor.R`, function `.cor_test`. So run

```
trace(ggpubr:::.cor_test, edit=TRUE)
```

and edit `italic(R)` to become `rho` in

```
if (output.type == "expression") {
    z <- z %>% dplyr::mutate(r.label = paste("rho", r, sep = "~`=`~"),
```

After saving, run your code and get the following graph.

[image]

Comment: Just saw your answer. I did not realise he meant the symbol rho. Not easy to have italics inside text i guess.

Comment: Really helpful, instead of "rho" I tried "'rho'" (just used a pair of ' ' inside the brackets) and it returned "rho" instead of "ρ".